# “waiting for target device to come online” Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

[image]

And later nothing happens. anyone idea?
[image]

Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Answer (score 0):

First step check your current adb version at terminal. Now actual is 1.0.32. If you have older version - update it. If it doesn`t help try to install additional packages in sdk manager. In my case - install that choosed at screenshot solved the problem.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSuBl.png)